# Declaring inherited generics with complex type constraints

Tags: c#

I have an interface with a single generic type parameter:

```
public interface IDriveable<T> where T : ITransmission { ... }
```

I also have a class that has a type parameter that needs to be of that interface type:

```
public class VehicleFactory<T> where T : /* ??? */
```

There is a problem here with this declaration. I can't put "IDriveable", because that has no type parameters and doesn't match the type signature of IDriveable. But I also don't want to put IDriveable<U> either, because then VehicleFactory has to know what *kind* of IDriveable it's getting. I want VehicleFactory to accept *any* kind of IDriveable.

The proposed solution a coworker had was to use:

```
public class VehicleFactory<T, U> where T : IDriveable<U>
```

But I don't like this, since it's redundant. I have to say the "U" type twice:

```
var factory = new VehicleFactory<IDriveable<AllWheelDrive>, AllWheelDrive>();
```

What should go in the question marks?

Comment: Why must IDriveable<T> be a parameter? Can't you use an IDriveable<T> inside the class and only get the AllWheelDrive parameter?

Answer (score 3):

What is VehicleFactory going to *do* with T? Does it actually need the constraint in order to work, or is it just for the sake of developer sanity checking?

One common way round this is to declare a non-generic interface (`IDriveable`) and then make your generic one extend that:

```
public interface IDriveable {}
public interface IDriveable<T> : IDriveable {}
public class VehicleFactory<T> where T : IDriveable
```

If you *do* want the factory to be able to do things with `T`, you could put any interface members from `IDriveable<T>` which don't care about `T` into the nongeneric `IDriveable`.

Comment: The factory does need to be able to do things with the IDriveable type parameter. Also, I don't think this solution works, because IDriveable<T> has type constraints in the original example, and I think that might cause logical (if not compilation?) errors here.

Comment: I wonder if in fact I'm not trying to have my cake and eat it too, here. There seems to be a design decision made by the language not to allow this kind of thing implicitly, possibly with very good reason.

Comment: Well, for one thing a single type could implement multiple IDriveable<T> interfaces... which T should it pick?

Comment: Indeed where people want to avoid a type parameter they are normally 'making the choice in their head' and wishing the compiler would do the same, compilers don't like ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
public class VehicleFactory<T, U> where T : IDriveable<U>
```

This will let the factory know what types the driveables are.

Comment: it looks like you was one min faster than me, exactly the same answer ;-)

Comment: That seems less than optimal. Won't I have to write "VehicleFactory<IDriveable<AllWheelDrive>, AllWheelDrive>"? That's kind of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the VehicleFactory with 2 types generics and anign one of them to the interface. something like:

```
public class VehicleFactory<T1,T2> where T1 : IDriveabel<T2>
```

I hope that ist not what you ment with the Idriveable. I guess the U is a specific type. Like String, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten often used cases like this:

```
interface IDriveableAllWheel : IDriveable<AllWheelDrive>
{}

var factory = new VehicleFactory<IDriveableAllWheel, AllWheelDrive>();
```

or even

```
class AllWheelFactory : VehicleFactory<IDriveableAllWheel, AllWheelDrive>
{}
```

also see a kvb's answer in [Calling Generic Property In Generic Class From Interface Implemented By Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197211/calling-generic-property-in-generic-class-from-interface-implemented-by-generic-c) for possible workaround.